# Safari Responsive Design Mode

Tags: safari, responsiveness

Does Safari's responsive design mode only work if you're using something like bootstrap? I'm pretty much a rookie here and haven't implemented Bootstrap (yet) on my site, BUT when I view my site ([www.gdbdp.com/at/html5](http://www.gdbdp.com/at/html5)) in Safari with Responsive Design Mode turned on and iPhone selected, it looks almost NOTHING like what it actually looks like on my phone. On the phone, the images scale down accordingly, but in RDM they don't, they're huge.

I would expect that, no matter how your site is coded, RDM would simply strive to be an approximation of what the page looks like on a specified device/browser. Trying to determine if there is a minimum expected level of responsiveness I have to implement before Responsive Design Mode will work.

Any input appreciate. Thanks,
dp

Comment: It shouldn't have anything to do with Bootstrap (which is just code thats been written for you). It just seems that Safari's Responsive Design Mode sucks hard.

Answer (score 2):

Safari's responsive design mode feature was working flawlessly until update in February. We have tested views by comparing actual device views to Safari RDM and clearly something is wrong.  We have changed to using Chrome's RDM.  Chrome's UI is not as elegant for presentations but is very accurate and provides better preview on Android devices.